# Verificação in-line no Python 3

Tags: python

Quero colocar o valor de uma variavel e se esse valor não estiver disponível colocar outro.
EX:

```js
variavel = 1 || 0
```

Isso é possível no Javascript, mas quero saber se há alguma maneira de faze-lo no python.
O que eu tentei foi:

```py
centena = numero[-3] or '0'
```

(No caso do python a variavél 'numero' seria uma string)

Comment: E o que seria a posição -3 dessa sua string?

Comment: a centena de um número

Comment: E o que espera com a verificação? Retornar zero se o número não possuir a centena?

Comment: Matemática não resolve? Exemplo: `numero // 100 % 10` retorna a centena ou zero...

Comment: isso mesmo que eu queria fazer

Comment: @fernandosavio com certeza serve mas não tem um jeito de fazer como eu exemplifiquei?

Comment: `number` e `numero` são a mesma coisa? Se sim, `trunc` retorna um valor inteiro, não uma *string*.

Comment: @Woss eu tinhas escrito mal desculpa, agora esta como no meu codigo

Comment: **1)** Você está convertendo o `input()` para float e depois para `int` através do `math.func()`.. Então não sei porque você está tentando trabalhar com strings no seu código. **2)** _"não tem um jeito de fazer como eu exemplifiquei"_ Não entendi, você quer uma solução para o problema ou você quer que a sua solução funcione? Pois acredito que você tentou usá-la e não funcionou...

Comment: @fernandosavio estou começando agora no python e achei que esse jeito evitaria alguns problemas de crash no códigol, como uma pessoa digitando um número quebrado. o "como eu exemplifiquei" seria como no próprio javascript onde uma variavel pode receber um valor ou outro. EX: `variavel = input || 'nada'`. onde input seria uma string qualquer e se o usuario não digitasse coisa alguma o valor da variavel seria 'nada'

Comment: Se vc quer garantir que foi digitado um número inteiro, basta usar `int` e capturar o `ValueError`. Ex: https://ideone.com/ejw5YH - nesse caso eu peço para o usuário digitar outro número, mas você poderia simplesmente setar outro valor na variável dentro do bloco `except`, por exemplo. Não se apegue ao que outras linguagens fazem, cada uma é de um jeito e nem sempre há uma equivalência 1 pra 1 de todos os recursos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você até consegue utilizar o operador `or` para algo como deseja pois este operador irá avaliar o primeiro operando e retorná-lo se este for avaliado como verdadeiro ou retornará o segundo operando (sem avaliá-lo).

Assim, seria possível fazer algo como:

```py
def foo(x):
  return x or '42'

print(foo(False))  # 42
print(foo(0))  # 42
print(foo(True))  # True
print(foo('1'))  # 1
```

Mas não conseguirá fazer `numero[-3] or '0'` para retornar `'0'` quando o valor `numero[-3]` não existir, isso porque em Python será lançada uma exceção `IndexError`, interrompendo a execução do operador `or`.

O equivalente a isso seria

```
try:
  return numero[-3]
except IndexError:
  return '0'
```

Ou verificar antes se a *string* `numero` possui pelo menos três caracteres.

De qualquer forma, nada justifica não utilizar a solução matemática para resolver o problema de obter o dígito das centenas:

```
centena = (numero // 100) % 10
```

Sendo `numero` um valor numérico. Isso já retornará a centena, quando existir, ou 0 se o valor for menor que 100, como o Fernando citou [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/419970/verifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-in-line-no-python-3?noredirect=1#comment816770_419970).

Comment: Muito obrigado, bela explicação. O melhor ainda é que posso usar o `or` como você para outras verificações no futuro, valeu mesmo.